# Magento CE 1.9.1

Tags: category, blocks, widget, link

When I try to add a category link widget in a static block I get an 404 error in the frontend.

I use the standard option available in CE 1.9.1.
Code in the editor look like this:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Type 4" title="Type 4" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/62"}}
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is correct. Make sure that the category is active.